# Upload and Retrieve: Python

Tags: python

I want to upload and retrieve files, through an API for free in Python. Are there any good API's for my purpose?

If you suggest the cloud like MongoDB, please give me an example code of upload and retrieve. I want to be able to upload in one computer and retrieve it from another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Mega`. It has a great API that can be integrated effortlessly.

And it has 20GB cloud storage too.

Checkout [MEGA](https://mega.io/doc)